# Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Models\User::$profile has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Hey I'm using laravel 9I have a relationship between two models in my application: Users and Profile. The User model has a hasOne relationship with the profile model. When I try to run an update method from my Profile Controller I get the error: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$profile has no effect.
This is my update method:

```
public function update(Request $request){  
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'province'=>'required',
            'bio'=>'required',
            
        ]);

        $user=Auth::user();
        $user->name= $request->name;
        $user->profile->province= $request->province;
        $user->profile->gender= $request->gender;
        $user->profile->bio= $request->bio;
        $user->profile->facebook= $request->facebook;
        $user->save();
        $user->profile->save();
        if($request ->has('password'))
        {
            $user->password=  bcrypt($request->password);
            $user->save();
           
        }
        return Redirect()->back();

    }
```

and this is user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    /**
     * Get the user associated with the User
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function profile(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(profile::class);
    }
}
```

and this is profile model

```
class profile extends Model 
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table ='profile_users';
    protected $primarykey='user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['province','user_id','bio','facebook' ];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the profile
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id' );
    }


    
}
class profile extends Model 
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table ='profile_users';
    protected $primarykey='user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['province','user_id','bio','facebook' ];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the profile
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id' );
    }


    
}
```

new code :

```
public function update(Request $request){  
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'province'=>'required',
            'bio'=>'required',
            
        ]);
        

        $user=Auth::user();
        $profile = $user->profile()->firstOrNew();
        $profile->whatever = 'whatever';                                                                                                                                   
        $user->name= $request->name;
        $user->profile->province= $request->province;
        $user->profile->gender= $request->gender;
        $user->profile->bio= $request->bio;
        $user->profile->facebook= $request->facebook;
        $user->save();
        $profile->save();
        if($request ->has('password'))
        {
            $user->password=  bcrypt($request->password);
            $user->save();
           
        }
        return Redirect()->back();

    }
```

Comment: I believe that if `$user->profile` is `null`, then code like `$user->profile->whatever = 'whatever'` will trigger that error. Does the `$user` record being updated actually have an associated profile? You may need to do `$profile = $user->profile()->firstOrNew();`, then `$profile->whatever = 'whatever;`, and finally `$profile->save();`

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i still getting same error

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72875444/edit) with your new code and the associated error message. You saying "I tried it and it still doesn't work" is basically useless, since we can't see _what_ you tried.

Comment: can you edit it for me please ?

Comment: Uh... No? Edit your own question and show your new code. I asked you to try something, you said you did and it didn't work. I need to see the new code you tried so I can determine _why_ it failed... How would me editing your question accomplish that???

Comment: i did it check it now

Comment: Oh c'mon! I didn't mean actually use `->whatever`. That is an example! Replace `->whatever` with your actual code! And get rid of all your `$user->profile-> ...` lines. `$profile->province = $request->province;`, `$profile->gender= $request->gender;`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Dumping code from comments:

```php
$user = Auth::user();

$user->name = $request->name;

$user->save();

$profile = $user->profile()->firstOrNew();

$profile->province = $request->province;
$profile->gender = $request->gender;
$profile->bio = $request->bio;
$profile->facebook = $request->facebook;

$profile->save();
```

I very obviously did not mean actually use `->whatever`; that was just an example; use the correct properties and your code should work.

Comment: Apologies for any sarcasm/frustration from my comments, but you really need to learn how to handle pesudo-code; your code doesn't have `$user->profile->whatever = 'whatever'` anywhere in it, so me saying that does not mean literally use `$profile->whatever = 'whatever'`, it means for each property you want to save, use `$profile-> ...` instead, like `$profile->province = $request->province;`, and the same for `gender`, `bio`, `facebook`, etc. Learning that, and not relying on copying/pasting code from Stackoverflow will make you a much better and more valuable developer. Good luck!

Comment: ill do my best ,thanks again